# making fgets not print stuff like ^G or ^D caused by arrow keys or other control keys

Tags: c, input, fgets

Basically the title is self explaining. I'm programming in C and i use fgets as the input function but i do not want that control characters get printed.

Comment: but it shows you what you type even ugly looking control characters

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`fgets()` is rather simple, and doesn't offer you much control over what appears on the screen. I don't think that it's possible to do this. You may want to look into something more powerful - like [readline](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, as other post says, `readline` is your best bet. Its simple too. If you are on Linux, it should already be installed. try the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <readline/readline.h>
#include <readline/history.h>

// compile as:  gcc <file>.c -lreadline -lcurses 
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *input = readline("Enter words: ");
    printf("\n Input: [%s]\n", input );
    return 0;
}
```

--
HTH.

Comment: I compiled with lreadline and lcurses but i get readline/readline.h no such file or directory, i've checked with apt-get install libreadline6 and it is installed, what's wrong?

Comment: I've found the library in /lib but why doesn't it get linked? Do i need to configure the search path of gcc?

Comment: `apt-get install libreadline6-dev` should fix that problem.  Usually if you can't find a header file, check to see if the <package>-dev (development package) is installed.

Comment: To elaborate on @ChronoKitsune's helpful advice: The library versions without "-dev" are just the runtime libraries for *already compiled, finished programs*. They are loaded automatically when a normal user starts a program which was dynamically linked against them. No header are needed, for that, of course. If you *develop* programs, by contrast, you need header files and maybe some other supporting files, too.